# How can I call function or object name in string variable? actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I need to call an object or function name with string variable.
For example;

```
var item_1:Object;
var str:String = "item_1";
TweenLite.to(item_1, 2, {alpha:0});
```

it's working but,
 if I do something like below its not working

```
var item_1:Object;
var str:String = "item_1";
TweenLite.to(str, 2, {alpha:0});
```

how can do that? thanks from now..

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
this[str];
//or
root[str]
```

All objects in AS3 can be accessed as  `object[key]=value`

So, if you know where `item_1` is declared, you can call it as `itemParent["item_1"]` or in your example, `itemParent[str]`

Answer (score 2):

I'm having some trouble reading your question, but it seems like you're looking for the following:

```
var item_1:Object
var str:String = "item_1"
TweenLite.to(this[str], 2, {alpha:0});
```

To dynamically access objects by their id from a string, you need to use the `this["itemid"]` notation.

Comment: @sch Ah. I've never encountered the need to use this notation, so I'm not familiar with its limitations. Thanks.

Comment: ah dammit! undone by a slow internet connection!! :P  @sch you're right, but I guess we **should** get the benefit of the doubt, no?

Comment: Yeah I believe that the "dynamic" keyword in flash should be completely removed. Dynamic resolution can ONLY promote poor coding practice and as such will always lead to slower performance. That's why you never see any of the mature languages employ such an atrocious feature.